# Reading global value from multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, d

C++ programmer here learning D.
This is a very simplified example to demonstrate the issue I'm having in my real code. I'm fully aware of the code style issues with global variables, I just want to understand why this doesn't work.

I have a "global" variable which I initialize in the main program before creating any threads. I then have some threads that read that variable. It is **never** written to after it is set so there ought to be no race conditions reading it without synchronization after it is set.

But it doesn't work. I never see the value 12 in my threads, they always read the value 0.
I know that in C++ you should use either a mutex or an std::atomic variable to ensure that values written in one thread are visible in another, and likely the same is true in D, however I would have assumed that the call to spawn is almost 100% likely to have done something to synchronize plus I experimented with a mutex and even when I tried to protect the value with a mutex I still see 12 in the main thread and 0 in the spawned thread.

Is there something I need to do to make this work?

No matter what I do I get :-

```
From thread A=0
From main   A=12
```

The code is :-

```
import std.concurrency;
import std.stdio;
import core.thread;

int a;

void myThread()
{
    writeln("From thread A=", a);
}

void main()
{
    a = 12;
    spawn(&myThread);
    Thread.sleep(2.seconds);
    writeln("From main   A=", a);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables in D are thread-local by default. Either use `shared` or `__gshared`.

Comment: Ah right or course, I knew this, just didn't think of it in this context. The perils of C++ and D being similar I suppose. Thank you.